# How do I decode this binary string in python?

Tags: python, binary

So, I have this string `01010011101100000110010101101100011011000110111101110100011010000110010101110010011001010110100001101111011101110111100101101111011101010110010001101111011010010110111001100111011010010110110101100110011010010110111001100101011000010111001001100101011110010110111101110101011001100110100101101110011001010101000000000000`

and I want to decode it using python, I'm getting this error
`UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xb0 in position 280: invalid start byte`

According to this webiste: https://www.binaryhexconverter.com/binary-to-ascii-text-converter

The output should be `S�ellotherehowyoudoingimfineareyoufineP`

Here's my code:

```
def decodeAscii(bin_string):
    binary_int = int(bin_string, 2);
  
    byte_number = binary_int.bit_length() + 7 // 8
    binary_array = binary_int.to_bytes(byte_number, "big")
    ascii_text = binary_array.decode()
    
    print(ascii_text)
```

How do I fix it?

Comment: The `�` in the output seems to indicate a weird character outside the normal ascii range. Why is that there?

Comment: @khelwood I'm trying to transfer data over the audio and this binary string was received by the receiver, where there is no error-correcting techniques were implemented. And that's the reason for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your bytes simply cannot be decoded as utf-8, just as the error message tells you.

utf-8 is the default encoding parameter of [decode](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes.decode) - and the best way to put in the correct encoding value is to **know** the encoding - otherwise you'll have to guess.

And guessing is probably what the website does, too, by trying the most common encodings, until one does not throw an exception:

```
def decodeAscii(bin_string):
    binary_int = int(bin_string, 2);
    byte_number = binary_int.bit_length() + 7 // 8
    binary_array = binary_int.to_bytes(byte_number, "big")
    ascii_text = "Bin string cannot be decoded"
    for enc in ['utf-8', 'ascii', 'ansi']:
        try:
            ascii_text = binary_array.decode(encoding=enc)
            break
        except:
            pass
    print(ascii_text)

s = "01010011101100000110010101101100011011000110111101110100011010000110010101110010011001010110100001101111011101110111100101101111011101010110010001101111011010010110111001100111011010010110110101100110011010010110111001100101011000010111001001100101011110010110111101110101011001100110100101101110011001010101000000000000"
decodeAscii(s)
```

Output:

```
S°ellotherehowyoudoingimfineareyoufineP
```

But there's no guarantee that you find the "correct" encoding by guessing.

Answer (score 1):

Your binary string is just not a valid ascii or utf-8 string. You can tell  `decode` to ignore invalid sequences by saying

```
ascii_text = binary_array.decode(errors='ignore')
```

Comment: Just keep in mind that this will more likely lead to a loss of actual data, compared to the ``try..except`` approach. E.g. ``print("Hello Wörld".encode("ansi").decode(errors='ignore'))`` will throw away the ``ö``, while the ``try...except`` approach might eventually guess the correct encoding.

Answer (score 1):

**It could be solved in one line:**

Try this:

```
def bin_to_text(bin_str):
    bin_to_str = "".join([chr(int(bin_str[i:i+8],2)) for i in range(0,len(bin_str),8)])

    return bin_to_str

bin_str = '01010011101100000110010101101100011011000110111101110100011010000110010101110010011001010110100001101111011101110111100101101111011101010110010001101111011010010110111001100111011010010110110101100110011010010110111001100101011000010111001001100101011110010110111101110101011001100110100101101110011001010101000000000000'
bin_to_str = bin_to_text(bin_str)
print(bin_to_str)
```

**Output:**

```
S°ellotherehowyoudoingimfineareyoufineP
```